# Transactions before blockchain sync?

Tags: synchronization

I withdrew some bitcoins from a site and the blockchain is not synced yet. It's taking too long for the sync (more than a day). The payment is still not in my wallet. Can I send payment to another wallet before it's synced ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can send bitcoins to any wallet at anytime you want.

The transaction will be shown in the wallet after it synced.